# Linearity of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a way to derive the fact: $\langle cA, C\rangle = c\langle A, C \rangle$ from $\langle cA + B, C \rangle = c \langle A, C \rangle + \langle B, C \rangle$?

$\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is an inner product and $A, B, C$ are vectors and $c$ is a scalar.

I tried this: plugging $B = 0$,

$$\langle cA + 0, C \rangle = \langle cA, C \rangle = c \langle A, C \rangle + \langle 0, C \rangle$$

I do not know what to do with $\langle 0, C \rangle$.

Comment: Try plugging $c=1$, $A=B=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Usually $\langle cA, C\rangle = c\langle A, C \rangle$ can be also taken as part of the definition, anyway if you have $\langle cA + B, C \rangle = c \langle A, C \rangle + \langle B, C \rangle$ then as you did just plug $B = 0$ and you obtain
$$\langle cA + 0, C \rangle = \langle cA, C \rangle = c \langle A, C \rangle + \langle 0, C \rangle$$ 
The part $\langle 0, C \rangle=0$ you obtain from linearity i.e. take a base {$e_i$} of the space and then you write all your vectors in this base so that you have $$C=c^ie_i, 0=0e_i$$.
Calculating the inner product and considering that is linear 
$$\langle 0, C \rangle=\langle 0e_i,c^je_j \rangle= 0c^j\langle e_i,e_j \rangle=0 $$